# Is there a way to launch Canvas LMS External App (Plug-in) at login or show on main screen right after log-in?

Tags: lti, canvas-lms

I am trying to write an app that can integrate within the Canvas LMS/LTI, but be launched at login, or at minimum display on the main screen somewhere right after a student logs in as opposed to being configured to be inside a course or in a submenu somewhere out-of-view. Another option is to have it display a pop-up or show as a notification somehow, triggered based on certain conditions on the backend data.

So far I've only been able to add my app as an external app that must be manually launched by the student...so--> "out-of-sight...out-of-mind" as the saying goes. Ideally I need the student to see this and interact with once a day, either when they login, or based on some trigger. I don't want/need it to pop up when they are in the middle of working on homework or taking a quiz, but I do need them to see it daily somehow and not have it a link they need to remember to click on. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: And I am trying to start building plugin for canvas, struggling to find docs for it